# GWT RPC Call onFailure

Tags: exception, gwt, parameters, rpc

I created a Remote Procedure Call. The Server-Side connects to Webservices, to get Information, which it hands over to the Client-Side. This is the Client-Side Code.

```
public void statusFor(GwtLaneServiceAsync laneProxy){

    AsyncCallback<LaneInformation> callback = new AsyncCallback<LaneInformation>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LaneInformation information)
        {
            doStatusForSuccess(information);
        }
    };

    for (Lane lane : this.mainmenu.getSlidePanel().getLaneMenu().getProperLanes().values())
    {
        if (lane.isChecked().booleanValue())
            laneProxy.statusFor("admin", "password", true, lane.getId(), callback);
        else
            laneProxy.statusFor("admin", "password", false, lane.getId(), callback);
        this.laneIndex++;
    }
}
```

Now i wanna do the following...

When the Server can't reach the Webservice, a WebServiceException is thrown. If that happens, I wanna type "Offline" on one of my Buttons of the GUI. BUT I need to tell on which button. It can't be hard coded, cause it depends on which "lane" the Webservice failed.

1. I need to catch the Exceptions
2. I need to tell the "onFailure"-Part, on which lane, the Service failed.
   Can I somehow deliver the statusFor()-Parameters to that part?

Comment: is it  coming in to onfailure ?

Comment: Y, when it can't reach the Service

Comment: Thats purely exception handling ..

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap your `LaneInformation` in a generic response object and add the exception/an error code to that response, to signal that something went wrong on the server side, eg.:

```
public class RemoteResult<T> 
{
    T payload;
    String errorCode;
}
```

and

```
public abstract class AbstractAsyncCallBack<T> implements AsyncCallback<RemoteResult<T>>
{
    public void onSuccess( RemoteResult<T> rr ) 
    {
        if ( rr.getErrrorCode() != null ) { failure( rr.getErrorCode() ); }
        else { success( rr.getPayload() ); }
    }

    public abstract void success( T payload );
    public void failure( String errorCode ) { /* Ignore by default */ }
}
```

To conclude, you shouldn't throw an exception on the server side when the server can't connect to some other service, you should communicate that nicely to the client, and that's not by (re)throwing the exception :-)

The `onFailure()` method is mostly for when things go wrong in the RPC communication proper.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

There is no of ways to handle such case. you can throw any custom exception from server side while server can't reach the webservice. then it will come `onFailure` block. or you can return any message string in response variable. Here response variable you are using  `LaneInformation` bean. so take new variable there like `result`, and set message as per your requirement.

`OnFailure` it comes only when any exception occurred or any wrong thing happens in RPC call.